# color first five rows of a table in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2017

Iam developing a report where I need to provide special effects on 1st few columns. How can I color code or provide 3D effect for first five rows of a table in SSRS? Also,  count of values in these columns?

For example:

```
    My date    count

        A                  3
         B                  4
         C                   1
          D                   1
          E                   5
          F                   6
          G                   7
```

Now,  I should color rows start from A to E and get total count of that ( e.g. 14 in this case)

How can I I acheive this?

Answer (score 3):

While Strawberryshrub's answer would probably work just fine, there's an easier way that can get you the same result.  You should be able to use the SSRS function `RowNumber` to indicate which rows should be colored.  Try the following expression in the background color property for that row.

```
=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) < 6, "Green", "No Color")
```

Also, for the count that you need, you should be able to use a similar pattern.

```
=SUM(IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) < 6, Fields!count.Value, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to cathegorize your first column with an calculated field:

```
'Name: CustomCathegory
=IIF(Fields!MyDae.Value = "A" Or 
     Fields!MyDae.Value = "B" Or 
     Fields!MyDae.Value = "C" Or 
     Fields!MyDae.Value = "D" Or 
     Fields!MyDae.Value = "E", "Cathegory1", "CathegoryElse")
```

Now you can use the row coloring (font or background) and use the following expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!CustomCathegory = "Cathegory1", "Blue", "Black")
```

You can also sum by CustomCathegory (textbox outside the detail section)

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!CustomCathegory = "Cathegory1", Fields!Count.Value, 0))
```

or group your table by  CustomCathegory and add header or footer with the sum per CustomCathegory